# Symfony and Twig: it's better to pass the entire entity or to pass the single property into a dedicated array?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Symfony can pass the entire entity to a Twig template and from a Twig template it is possible to call get methods of the entity.

Calling get methods from inside a Twig template is a good practice or has some drawbacks, for example in terms of performances or consumed resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing entities directly is fine except in some performance or memory-intensive scenarios (huge resultsets in memory constrained environment...), in which cases you might have to fall back to passing along static data.

Also notice you don't have to explicitly call methods upon the entity in a twig file, since it behaves like the corresponding associative array twig-wise (twig is smart enough to hydrate the entity and call the getter for you on demand):

```
Display some entity property through its getter method : {{ entity.property }}
Display some array index value : {{ array.index }}
```

Comment: So, it is the same thing: calling get methods from a controller is the same thing as call it from a twig template?

Comment: that twig trick allows you not to access the entity from the controller, thus you have less code to write (the same twig template is also fully compatible with an array equivalent of your entity, should you need it at some point). It's not exactly the same since if an error happens, say, in the property getter, the resulting stack trace will be different since the execution of that getter happens much later when executing the php representation of that twig template.

Comment: also, as a corollary, accessing a property on an entity often triggers its hydration by the orm (actual populating with db data), which can be memory-intensive and lead to php out of memory errors, which is always a pain when you see it happen from a twig.